# Configure Nginx To Accept Domain Name

Tags: django, deployment, nginx

I bought a Domain Name today, changed the DNS to match the exact VPS IP and configured Nginx to run my app.

So far, I can connect to my app using the external ip, from any computer, but I still can't connect to it via the Domain Name.

I've set the server_name to be the exact domain name I purchased, is there anything left I must do?

Comment: What message are you getting when connecting via the domain name?

Comment: Could not locate domain.

Comment: Just tell your domain and ip address. It's may be invalid dns config, not delegated domain, dns update delay or may be something else.

Comment: Give it about 6 hours to update. Meanwhile you can ping your domain name from the terminal to see where it resolves. Once it shows your ip
you just have to configure nginx properly.

Answer (score 1):

it is DNS configuration problem.

for sure about reason open putty and see output about site content by curl or wget or lynx.
example:

```
lynx mysite.com
```

if it work and returned proper result nginx config is true but it is DNS problem.

dns problems:

- /etc/hosts
- /etc/hostname
- bad configuration

try `ping sitename.com` on your pc with ms dos. if has timeout then its not nginx problem.